# LTSP Client Boot Issue - Ubuntu 12.04 VMware

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, vmware, ltsp

Today I've been trying to get a virtual Ubuntu 12.04 LTSP server and client setup running in VMWare Fusion by following this guide. http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-create-ubuntu-1104-x64-ltsp-server-32bit-thin-clients  I'm using a Mid-2012 MacBook Pro, since I didn't want to try this on my actual Linux machines until I was 100% sure I could pull it off.

The server configuration was successful, and my thin client found and began booting off the network. From here, however, it 'hangs' on the Ubuntu starting screen for several minutes before finally failing. I am able to view the console text from both the TTY1 and TTY7 terminals, and have attached screenshots.

Does anyone know how to fix these errors? I have moderate Linux experience, but not very much with boot errors such as this. What do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks. The screenshots are below.

http://coe.eng.utah.edu/~lewandow/Screencaps